# Facebook Like Buttons shows a different count if the user is logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We use the Like buttons on our pages and the count is important. However, recently, the count has been lower for users that aren't logged into Facebook when viewing a given page.

I think this is because of the Open Graph.  It seems that Facebook counts general likes and likes that had open graph data included on the button when the user is logged into Facebook.  But when the user is not logged into Facebook - these counts only show likes and not the open graph likes - thus making the number lower...

This is causing issues for us - as we want the Like button to show the same amount of likes regardless if the user is logged into Facebook or not...

Any advice or a solution is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

This post that seems to explain exactly the scenario you are talking about. Essentially, the inflated number being reported is the total engagement count for this page (Likes and Shares) where are you are looking for the Fan Count (how many people explicitly hit the like button).

http://faso.com/fineartviews/21028/facebook-like-button-count-inaccuracies